# How to login to KDE Plasma without pressing enter?

Tags: kde, screen-lock, plasma5

At my lock screen in Plasma, I can start typing my password directly. What I want to do is that as soon as the password is correct, it should unlock. Say my password is "1234", on my lock screen, by only typing "1234", not "1234+Enter", I want to unlock.

This doesn't apply to SDDM, as that isn't accessed often; though an answer to that will also be welcome.

I wasn't able to find any similar answer by searching so sorry if this was a duplicate.

If it matters, I am using Arch Linux through Endeavour OS.

Comment: So you want to cause multiple invalid password authentication failure events whenever you unlock your screen?  one for each character in your password except the last character.  Sounds like a good way to auto-lock your account for repeated auth failures.   I doubt that you'll find any way to do this because nobody capable of implementing the idea would think it was a good one.

Comment: @cas It doesn't have to authenticate until it reaches the last character. So, only when there are 4 digits, it will authenticate.

Comment: it won't know that there's only 4 digits in your password, or when the password is correct unless it tries to authenticate with whatever you've typed so far. and do that again every time you type another character.